# Org Mode bullets indentation display differently between normal and server mode

Tags: org-mode, emacs-daemon, server

Does anybody has any clue why the same configuration yield different appearances between normal vs server-mode ?

Here's the normal mode (the correct one)

[image]

And here's when run Emacs in server-mode

[image]

(There are black star chars leading before each indented bullet.)

This problem occur regardless the theme used.

Updated:

As suggested by NickD: information of the point from both mode is identical:

```
                 position: 1234 of 2606 (47%), column: 0
            character: * (displayed as *) (codepoint 42, #o52, #x2a)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x2A
               script: latin
               syntax: _    which means: symbol
             category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 2a" or "C-x 8 RET ASTERISK"
          buffer code: #x2A
            file code: #x2A (encoded by coding system undecided-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    gdi:-outline-Monofur NF-normal-normal-normal-mono-13-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1 (#x2A)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: ASTERISK
  general-category: Po (Punctuation, Other)
  decomposition: (42) ('*')

There is an overlay here:
 From 1234 to 1245
  face                 hl-line
  priority             -50
  window               #<window 3 on lean.org>


There are text properties here:
  face                 org-hide
  fontified            t
  line-prefix          [Show]
  wrap-prefix          [Show]
```

Comment: Put your cursor on one of the "invisible" stars and do `C-u C-x =`: Emacs will show you a bunch of things about the character including a `face`, probably `org-hide`. Click on that face and see what it says its `Foreground` is (probably `black`). Also get  the frame background color with `(frame-parameter nil 'background-color)`. Do this for both cases and add the information to your question. It is probably the case the that the foreground of the `org-hide` face and the frame background color are not the same in the `server-mode` case, so the stars show through.

Comment: BTW, the bullets "indentation" is only partly indentation coming from `org-indent` mode; the other part is because the leading starts are made "invisible" through the `org-hide-leading-stars` setting. But the starts are still there if e.g. you `cat` the file in a terminal. I hope that clarifies what I'm asking you to do in the previous comment.

Comment: What happens if you turn off `hl-line-mode`? Do the invisible stars still bleed through?